# Selenium/Cucumber automation framework, how do I test a "remember my info" button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber

In my testing automation framework(selenium/cucumber), I am trying to test the checkbox for remembering my credentials on the website.
When doing it manually I have no issues, and upon signing off, my credentials are suggested in the correct fields. However, upon automation the suggestions aren't there.
Did any of you had this issue before, would be beyond grateful for any suggestions!

I was hoping that after the sign out step in my scenario, I would be able to locate my email and password in the fields and sign in again. However it says that it can not find the element, after sign out, which does not make sense, because the one it suggests doesn't even exist, and all my elements have id. I feel like I am going crazy, so would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: What is the program that "suggests your credentials"? When some program just simply could reuse your credentials without your approval, it's a perfect starting point for a cyber attack.